# Accidentally deleted /dev directory

Tags: udev, data-recovery, rm

I've accidentally performed

```
sudo rm -fr /dev
```

**Will I suffer from data loss** or any side effects?

I've rebooted the system and my data seems ok, but I'm afraid there is hidden or non-obvious loss of data that I simply haven't found out yet.

**EDIT:**

I've read [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/344465/recover-from-rm-rf-proc-sys-dev-pts-dev-without-reboot) but didn't get sure enough that no data loss happened; I need to be more sure.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Recover from rm -rf /proc /sys/ /dev/pts /dev without reboot?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/344465/recover-from-rm-rf-proc-sys-dev-pts-dev-without-reboot)

Comment: @muru I've read it, but didn't get sure enough that no DATA LOSS happened.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Look at the output of `mount`: you'll see that a `devtmpfs` (or `devfs`) filesystem is mounted there. In other words, all the device nodes you see there aren't stored anywhere "permanently". This is just a pseudo-filesystem that your software (the userland in cooperation with the kernel) populates with devices nodes that you can use to get *handles* to devices.

In other words, not only is /dev re-populated every boot, also, it's just used for getting handles. It's not the actual devices, nor the actual data on the devices.

The good thing is that you henceforth probably think twice before you hit enter on a `sudo rm -rf`, and no real harm was done :)